# Mounting the host Vm in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I want to mount the host vm in Docker for Windows in my container (for backup purpose). I found a short article about it which says to run

```
docker container run --rm -it -v /:/host alpine
```

to do this. I tried and it works fine. Now i wanted to put it into a docker-compose file. However

```
volumes:
  - / :/host:ro
```

doesn't work. I don't get an error message, the folder is just empty. The space in front of the colon was necessary, without it I got an error.

Does someone know how to set this up in docker-compose?

Answer (score 0):

Just write the same way you did on `docker run`, do not put any space between directories.

```
volumes:
   - /:/host:ro
```

But with `:ro` docker will not write anything to it and will simply read the contents of the directory. If you want to write, remove the `:ro`.

Comment: THanks for your reply. The ro makes it read only. This does not work, at least not on Windows. I get "invalid volume specification: '/host_mnt/host:rw" when there is no space in front of the colon, both with and without the ro.

Comment: Like I said in the question and comment, removing the space leads to an error.

Comment: Try with double quotes: `- "/:/host"`

Comment: Same error : " invalid volume specification: '/host_mnt/host:ro' "

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47687893/unable-to-add-volume-to-image-via-docker-compose) is your issue - Dockerfile.

Comment: Try single quotes? ;p

Comment: That issue is about relative paths, but I use an absolute path.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein Single quotes make no difference